# Split a column and get all the calculated lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table composed by :

| Id | Text | JobId | JobsIds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toto | 45 | 56,58 |
| 2 | tata | 45 | 45.51 |
| 3 | titi | 46 |  |

and I want to have :

| Id | Text | CalculatedJobId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toto | 45 |
| 1 | toto | 56 |
| 1 | toto | 58 |
| 2 | tata | 45 |
| 2 | tata | 51 |
| 3 | titi | 46 |

**What I've tried**

I've tried to cross apply :

```
SELECT 
   Id, Text, x.value as CalculatedJobId
FROM tbl_data
CROSS APPLY string_split(jobsIds, ',') x
WHERE x.value <> ''
```

But the case where the jobId is not included in JobsIds disapears, and the one where the jobsIds is empty disappears also. So I got :

| Id | Text | CalculatedJobId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toto | 56 |
| 1 | toto | 58 |
| 2 | tata | 45 |
| 2 | tata | 51 |

I've tried to cross apply twice but it isn't a correct syntax :

```
SELECT 
   Id, Text, x.value as CalculatedJobId, y.value
FROM tbl_data
CROSS APPLY string_split(jobsIds, ',') x
CROSS APPLY JobId y
WHERE x.value <> ''
```

I've tried whith cross join but that's not the solution neither... I can't figure it out the solution, could you help me please ?

Comment: How about union?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you need to concatenate the value of `JobId` first, and then split:

```sql
SELECT d.Id,
       d.Text,
       SS.value AS CalculatedJobId
FROM dbo.tbl_data d
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CONCAT_WS(',',d.JobID,d.jobsIds), ',') SS;
```

*Note: this assumes that the value of `JobsIds` for `Id` `3` is `NULL`* not *a zero length string (`''`). If it is the latter, I would suggest you should be storing `NULL` first, but otherwise you could use `NULLIF` to convert it to `NULL` in the function.*